# Proxygen http client using a connection pool (keep-alive)

Tags: folly, proxygen

I am writing a proxygen server that needs to make http request to other service.
I would like to have a connection pool to this other service (using keep-alive), and whenever I need to make a request to this service, I would like to peak one of those connections and issue a request. Then, after the request is finished, return this connection to the pool so it can be reused. 
I read the curl client in the examples of the proxygen project, but this only makes one request and close the connection.
Can anyone give me some insights on how to make an http client that handles a connection pool using proxygen/folly ?
Does proxygen/folly have a way of handling connection pools ? In that case where can I read about it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I'm in the same boat. This thread is about this issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/facebook-proxygen/m2OAWwGxZTc. Looks like ConnectionManager is the clue. If you figure it out before me, please share. Otherwise I will share mine